# How to iterate by time (in seconds) through an array with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this JSON object that contains an array of devices types and each type has an array of brands:

```
{
"types": [
    {
      "type": "phone",
      "brands": [“samsung”,”apple”,”LG”, … //a list of brands]
    },
    {"type": "PC",
      "brands": [“DELL”,”apple”,”HP”, … //a list of brands]
    },
    …// a list of types
]
```

}

Using [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) I can iterate through every array , but I want to show the list of brands one by one in the same button , every value is shown for 2 seconds , in infinite loop, but I can’t figure out a way to do that.

Comment: increase a counter on every 2 seconds, may be with $timeout, and show that with types[count % types.length], without ng-repeat.

Comment: you can do it with $interval

Comment: @entre, yes, i wanted to say interval, but typed timeout, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need ng-repeat for this. given that you need to display only one element at a time.

```
vm.display = {
   count : 0,
   current :  null,
   repeat : function() { $interval( vm.display.changeElement(), 2*1000)  }
   changeElement : function() { vm.display.current =  list[vm.display.count] ; vm.display.count++; }
}
```

then just call vm.repeat() after getting data from server

Comment: It works thank you , I adjusted it to my data , but my web page seems to be a little slow , because i have too many data to show in the same way, is there any way to make it faster ?

Comment: Use pagination to get the data from server

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, you can use $interval instead of ng-repeat to do this.

```
$interval(function(){
      $scope.buttonLabel =$scope.data.types[0].brands[$scope.count%3];
      $scope.count++;
    },2000);
```

I hope this is what you need. :) 
http://plnkr.co/edit/8VIJAN?p=preview